# Rstrip based on regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, strip

I'm trying to validate a list of email addresses client-side. These addresses are separated by a comma or a semi-colon. They typically look like this:

```
'fake@mail.com; another@mail.com; '
'myaddress@mail.com, myfriend@mail.com'
```

I'm using a regular expression to split the string (I know how to validate each email address separately):

```
var separator = /[;,]+/;
var emails = value.split(separator);
```

I want to be able to remove the last separator if there is one. Server-side in python I'm doing something like that:

```
data = data.rstrip(separator)
value_list = re.split(separator, data)
```

With separator being the desired regexp.

My question is: how do I do this in Javascript ? More broadly, how do I remove the last characters of a string if they match a regexp ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rstrip can be done using *end line* `$` symbol in the regex for `.replace()` method. I have also changed your regular expression so that it can additionally remove spaces.

```
var separator = "[; ,]+",
    emails = value.replace(new RegExp(separator + "$"), "")
                  .split(new RegExp(separator));

console.log(emails);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works ! Is there a reason to use the Regexp object instead of the '/regexp/' notation I used ? I understand it was more flexible here to add the '$', I'm talking in a larger scope.

Comment: @PierreMourlanne There is no much difference, but yes, here regex literal prevents using string concatenation to add `$`, hence string and `new RegExp` was used (some say, this approach is sort of faster than regex literal but it always depends on browser and OS platform).